# Firebase screen class obfuscated while mapping is uploaded

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I'm using obfuscation for my Android app and I am using Firebase for crash reporting and some statistics. In the Firebase console I noticed that the `Screen class` was still obfuscated. I'm sure that the mapping file is uploaded because stacktraces are being deobfuscated.

Is there something else I need to configure or do to get the `Screen class` to show up deobfuscated in the console? I'm aware that I can add a `Screen name` manually but I think it defeats the whole purpose of obfustaction.

[image: Screen class image]